# What is the endpoint url for AWS StepFunctions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

[The documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html) defines the `endpoint` thusly:

> **endpoint (String)** — The endpoint URI to send requests to. The default endpoint is built from the configured `region`. The endpoint should be a string like `'https://{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com'`.

I believe the service name is `StepFunctions` and I'm using the region `us-east-1` so therefore the url should be:

```
https://stepfunctions.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

However this appears to not be right, what is the actual endpoint url for this service?

**Edit: (answer)**

```
https://states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you should manually edit the service endpoint, however, the `{service}` parameter is actually `states` for **`StepFunctions`** service.

The following should be your endpoint property:

```
Endpoint {              
  protocol: 'https:',                       
  host: 'states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: 443,                                    
  hostname: 'states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',                                           
  href: 'https://states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' }
```

Comment: I just had it set in my config as the default value and then I swap it using environment variables when testing locally. But yes, thanks that is the url I was looking for!